# configuring the SmtpServer to send email

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to send an email from my website that I've upgraded from .NET 1.1 to 2.0. The 1.1 version set the `SmtpServer` like this:

```
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = Current.Application.Item("SMTPServer")
```

It's using the `SmtpMail.SmtpServer` property from the old 'System.Web.Mail' namespace.

How do I set the `SmtpServer` without using any classes/properties from the old namespace? I've seen a couple of examples online that set the `SmtpServer` in the web.config file.

Is this the only way? How can you use an application setting in web.config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx).

You can also choose to set the server imperatively.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("my.server.com")
// ...
```